# Execute a function if Redis cache fails

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, redis, stackexchange.redis

I'm working on a .NET Core 3.1 application. Used 'StackExchange.Redis' library to handle Cache operations on Redis.

Configuring connection string in Startup.cs

```
services.AddStackExchangeRedisCache(options => {
    options.Configuration = Configuration.GetValue<string>("localhost:6379");
    options.InstanceName = "laserlamb:"; 
});
```

This static class adds 'SetRecord' function to IDistributedCache:

```
    public static class DistributedCache
    {
        public static bool isCacheAvailable = true;
        static DistributedCache()
        {

        }
        
        public static async Task SetRecord(this IDistributedCache cache, string recordId, string value)
        {
            try
            {
                if (this.isCacheAvailable)
                {
                    await cache.SetStringAsync(recordId, value);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.Error(e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

Using Dependency injection object to set record in Cache.

```
public class SomeRandomClass
{
    private IDistributedCache cache;
    public SomeRandomClass(IDistributedCache cache) { this.cache = cache; }
    
    public async Task SaveToCache()
    {
        await cache.SetRecord("Key", "Value");
    }
}
```

If my Redis instance is not running, there is an error throwing up.

How could I update `isCacheAvailable`, when cache is unavailable?

Comment: Not sure what you’re asking here. Can you show an example of what you want to happen if the cache is unavailable?

Comment: @stuartd I have updated the question and code. Please let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you want to check [Polly Project](http://www.thepollyproject.org/). It has `Retry/WaitAndRetry/RetryForever` and `Circuit Breakers` that can be handy.

You have [Plugin](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Polly.Caching.Distributed/) for Microsoft `DistributedCache` Provider.

Check it out.

Comment: Thank you. I know about polly but never though that it would work there. :)

Comment: Of course it would, it's good for this situations where you want to Retry and fallback to logging.

Comment: If you don't get it how you can solve with Polly - ping me up. But basically you can have Retry (if you want), along with Fallback policy for Logging or calling another method. Than you can combine them into one Policy. :) But, great, simple but yet powerful thing.

Comment: Worked perfectly. I was banging my head till 3am trying to figure out how to solve this. Your solution is simple and quite effective. Thanks a lot @Sasaman 

Comment: Great, it can be used in a lot situations, keep it in your sleeves. ^_^

Comment: Roger that.. 